# Access Cell Values of dataGridView (Form 1) into Form 2 causing index out of Range

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have made public my dataGridView in Form 1 and I can access its `HeaderText` from the 2nd Form but I can't access any of the other property / values of `dataGridView`.
I am taking value of gridLoopCount from Form1 by `int gridLoopCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;`

So, my loop works, I have tried it by changing my graphics string `e.Graphics.DrawString("my value"......`

**Here is the code of Form 2:**

```
 //Drawing the data grid
            Recieve_Donation_Stock rds = new Recieve_Donation_Stock();

            e.Graphics.DrawString(label7.Text, label7.Font, Brushes.Black, (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + label7.Location.X), (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + label7.Location.Y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rds.dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText, label9.Font, Brushes.Black, (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + label9.Location.X), (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + label9.Location.Y));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rds.dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText, label10.Font, Brushes.Black, (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + label10.Location.X), (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + label10.Location.Y));


            int j = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <=gridLoopCount; i++)
            {

                e.Graphics.DrawString(i.ToString(), label13.Font, Brushes.Black, (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + label7.Location.X), (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + label7.Location.Y + (15*j)));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(rds.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), label13.Font, Brushes.Black, (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + label9.Location.X), (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + label9.Location.Y + (15 * j)));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(rds.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), label13.Font, Brushes.Black, (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.X + label10.Location.X), (tableLayoutPanel2.Location.Y + label10.Location.Y + (15 * j)));
                j++;
            }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want, functionality-wise, on the second form? Should the `datagridview` on form 2 reflect the same data as the `datagridview` on form 1?

Comment: @alybaba726 I am printing `dataGridView` by placing my data on a new form and calling print even on `form_load`

Comment: I understand that from your code, I'm just trying to figure out why you'd call print.

Comment: Is `gridLoopCount` within `Form1` or `Form2`?  If it is in `Form1`, how does `Form2` know about it?